# Nitroshare loads, but icon doesn't appear in the menu bar

Tags: release-freya, applications

I installed NitroShare on this Freya-running laptop and a Windows desktop. The Windows version works like a charm, but the one on the laptop... Well, not so much.

I know for a fact, that the program itself works, because I can transfer files between the two and they go straight to the default folder (Desktop). The problem is that the menu bar icon doesn't show up, thus I can't edit any settings on the side of the laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug on NitroShare's side.
NitroShare doesn't recognize elementary OS' desktop environment (Pantheon) and that is the reason why it doesn't know how to display the indicator icon.
Now, let's make NitroShare believe we are using Ubuntu. Run the following command in the terminal:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=unity nitroshare
```

Nitroshare starts and it's icon shows up in Wingpanel as expected.
This is only a workaround, it's up to NitroShare's developer to fix this bug, please report it at Nitroshare's [issues site](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop/issues).

Comment: I know the developer personally. I'll pass this on.

Comment: Actually, there's already [an issue open](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop/issues/37) that deals with this. I'll look into getting this fixed for the next release. I tested the code that detects the current desktop environment in a number of Ubuntu editions and spin-offs but I don't think I tested elementary OS.